# ASP.NET Function called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get CurrentUserLocale, and I get it server-side from my CodeBehind.

This is what I do :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lang = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    [...]
    }
```

`lang` is a global `string`variable.

I have this function :

```
    public string getLang()
    {
        return lang;
    }
```

And in my JS code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var language = <%# getLang() %>;
        $("#datetimepickerdebut").datetimepicker({
            locale: language, // Eventuellement à modifier pour le multilingue
            showTodayButton: true,//Bouton d'accès rapide à la date-heure actuelle
            defaultDate: moment({h:0, m:0})/*Heure par defaut : le jour même à 00:00*/
        });
        $('#datetimepickerfin').datetimepicker({
            locale: language,
            showTodayButton: true,
            defaultDate: moment({h:23, m:59})
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried with `<% GetLang(); %>`, with `<%= GetLang(); %>`, with or without semi-colon. The calendar works well with `locale:'fr'` and when I set `var language = 'fr'`

Do you have any idea ?

Yann

Comment: Why don't you have a hidden field on the page that is populated with the lang value during the OnPageLoad event and just read the value from that field in the javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$language = '<%= getLang() %>';
```

Notice the single quotes around it? You have to keep in mind that the value needs to be a string in the client side, so you need to put it within quotes.

The `<%# %>` syntax is for data binding, you would have to call bind on a parent object for that to work.

---

Alternatively, as [Stoward94](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3420171/stoward94) suggests, you can use a hidden field.

```
//markup
<asp:HiddenField ID="LanguageHF" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" />

//js    
$language = document.getElementById('LanguageHF').value;

//code behind   
LanguageHF.Value = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

Comment: Had to wait 7 minutes ;)